Unsubscribe before second subscription
How  unsubscribe in rxjs before second subscription of Subject without takeUntil? I have DI service with a lot of chunks observables. For simplify I shorted it for one problem.
const test$ = new Subject();

function someFunctionSub(n) {
  this.destroy$.next(true);
  test$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((res) => console.log(n));
}

someFunctionSub(1); // first sub
test$.next(true);

setTimeout(() => {
someFunctionSub(2); // second sub
}
, 1000);


I need to unsubscribe before the second subscription call. But this.destroy$.next(true); It confuses me because I need 100500 times it call (it just in example one destroy$.next)
I trying switchMap but it not work for several subscriptions.
const test$ = new Subject();

function someFunctionSub(n) {

  test$.pipe(switchMap(res => of(res)).subscribe((res) => console.log(n));
}

someFunctionSub(1); // first sub
test$.next(true);

setTimeout(() => {
someFunctionSub(2); // second sub
}
, 1000);

//1
//1 - side effect several subscriptions
//2


take(1) it also not work because there is no guarantee that next will work for example
const test$ = new Subject();

function someFunctionSub(n) {

  test$.pipe(switchMap(res => of(res)).subscribe((res) => console.log(n));
}

someFunctionSub(1); // first sub
// test$.next(true); It can't call 

setTimeout(() => {
someFunctionSub(2); // second sub
test$.next(true);
}
, 1000);

//1 - side effect several subscriptions 
//2 - i need only 2



We can use switchMap which will always take the latest emissions and cancel all other emissions, we should ensure the  subject is a separate stream and the functions emit the current state of the subject.
import './style.css';

import { Subject, of, Subscription, switchMap } from 'rxjs';

const test$ = new Subject();
test$
  .pipe(
    switchMap((res: any) => of(res)) // switchMap cancels previous subscriptions and executes with current value of subject
    )
  .subscribe((res: any) => console.log(res));
function someFunctionSub(n: any) {
  test$.next(n);
}

someFunctionSub(1); // first sub

setTimeout(() => {
  someFunctionSub(3); // second sub
}, 1000);

// to destroy the subscription use
someFunctionSub(2); // second sub

Stackblitz Demo

We can use Subscription object to subscribe old subscription and initiate new one.
import './style.css';

import { Subject, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

const test$ = new Subject();
let sub: Subscription;
function someFunctionSub(n: any) {
  if (sub) {
    sub.unsubscribe();
  }
  sub = test$.subscribe((res: any) => console.log(n));
}

someFunctionSub(1); // first sub
test$.next(true);

setTimeout(() => {
  someFunctionSub(2); // second sub
  test$.next(true);
}, 1000);

// to destroy the subscription use
someFunctionSub(3); // second sub
sub.unsubscribe();
test$.next(true);

Stackblitz Demo

thank you for answer, however that's not quite it  because if i have N Subject i need create n sub (sub1 sub2 ... subn) and N IF. If there was some operator that would unsubscribe from the first one when you subscribe again

@KostiantynOkhotnyk updated my answer, switchMap could be best!

@KostiantynOkhotnyk If you are making a http api call using angular, it auto unsubscribes on completion, but does my latest suggestion help?

Unfortunately this case not work because I have a lot of subscriptions not one.

@KostiantynOkhotnyk if you are using http calls, they autocomplete so you  do not need any extra code

I agree with you for autocomplete this is the best. But I have another problem. There is button with a big process: saving indexedDb, modals, timers crypto itc. This button  has one process with a lot of Subjects in different modules and services, it work and need unsubsribe in this process (not destroy component). And i find solution without IF without variables destroy(destroy1, ... destroyN).

And the problem comes down to the fact that I call a function again in which I was already Subject and i need create destroy2 and call Next . Or if exist  sub.unsubscribe();
